# Java concurrency in practice - Listing 5.11

Tags: java, concurrency

In JCiP book, at [listing 5.11](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/listings/TestHarness.java), is this code will wait forever if any of `Thread t` is interrupted (because `startGate.await()` can throw `InterruptedException`) so endGate latch will never be released ?

```
public class TestHarness { 
public long timeTasks(int nThreads, final Runnable task) 
        throws InterruptedException { 
    final CountDownLatch startGate = new CountDownLatch(1); 
    final CountDownLatch endGate = new CountDownLatch(nThreads); 

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) { 
        Thread t = new Thread() { 
            public void run() { 
                try { 
                    startGate.await(); 
                    try { 
                        task.run(); 
                    } finally { 
                        endGate.countDown(); 
                    } 
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { } 
            } 
        }; 
        t.start(); 
    } 

    long start = System.nanoTime(); 
    startGate.countDown(); 
    endGate.await(); 
    long end = System.nanoTime(); 
    return end-start; 
}}
```

Comment: sthupahsmaht, regardless on if he tries it. Its a valid question considering it is being published in a widely used and highly cited book.

Comment: yes, i tried and it waits. Still can't believe if this bug is in the book, hoping that someone will explain that i'm wrong

Comment: Looks indeed like a flaw. It is not in the errata list for the book: http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/errata.html If you really think there is an error then you can submit it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not wrong.  The code will in fact hang.  Keep in mind, many of their code examples are written to give the reader and understanding of what the code snippet is supposed to functionally do.  They do not intend for developers to use their code out of the box without testing of their own.

For example, someone was asking about creating a self populating cache.  Someone pointed to the Memoizer section in JCiP where Tim Peierls followed with:

> The Memoizer class presented in that
>   section is only to illustrate a
>   technique. It lacks a number of useful
>   features, and it is nowhere near
>   production-ready.
>
> Use MapMaker anywhere you might have
>   been tempted to use or adapt Memoizer.

http://old.nabble.com/How-to-implement-a-self-populating-memoizer-cache--td30121001.html